# How to disable rotation in View Controller, while there are happening some specific actions?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, screen-rotation

Is there ay specific value or method of View Controller to disable rotation, while there are going some specific actions? For example, I want to allow rotation on this View Controller for all time, except only one thing.

```
func deleteAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Remove") { (action, view, completion) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.showActivityIndicator()
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        SingleTon.shared.deleteWordFromVocabulary(word: SingleTon.shared.getWords()[indexPath.section][indexPath.row], indexPath: indexPath.row)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.stopActivityIndicator()
        }
    }
}
```

When activity indicator appears, i want to disable my View Controller rotation. And when my activity indicator dissapears, i want to enable View Controller rotation back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a method that you can use to limit the supported interface orientations:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask { self.restrictRotation /* could be limited or not */ }
```

it should be inside `AppDelegate`, but you can use something like Notification/Observer or some delegation pattern to pass the restriction to the `AppDelegate` or set it from elsewhere.